# How to get combined resolution of all connected displays to Linux machine in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, x11, screen-resolution

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23492180/1997354) related, but not directly answering my question, which is:

How to get combined resolution of all connected displays to Linux machine in C++? (rectangle around all monitors, whichever placed)

I know quite little of C++, but I've written this code, unsure if it does the job correctly or not, as I do not have multiple monitors layout, I'm just coding something which will have to take into account all connected monitors.

Excerpt of my code follows:

```cpp
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <iostream>


        Display * my_display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
        Screen * my_screen = XDefaultScreenOfDisplay(my_display);

        const int screen_width = my_screen->width;
        const int screen_height = my_screen->height;

        if (x_coord >= screen_width)
        {
            std::cerr
                << "X coord bigger than the screen width\n";

            return 1;
        }

        if (y_coord >= screen_height)
        {
            std::cerr
                << "Y coord bigger than the screen height\n";

            return 1;
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Say I have one HD monitor and one 4K monitor, how would you define their combined resolution?

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367354/obtaining-list-of-all-xorg-displays

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. rectangle around all monitors, whichever placed (I quote from my question)

Comment: This does not provide an unambiguous definition.

Comment: By the way, "display", "screen" and "monitor" are three distinct entities in the X11 world. The screen resolution you get is the combined resolution of all monitors as managed by xrandr.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way seems to be (invoking shell commands not included in the answer, but shall be very simple):

```bash
xdpyinfo | awk '/dimensions:/ { print $2 }'
```

Comment: In a multi-monitor setup this will show the dimensions of the bounding box which contains all monitors.

Credit: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2682/126755